# why i get problem while running apache2 in ubuntu?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

Here is my details about the apache error, hope you will can find out the problems

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-02-25 12:06:14 +0545; 13min ago
  Process: 25134 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Comment: Possibly because the apache2.service is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Please check first : `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

After you have comprehended which procedure utilizes port **80**, you can choose in the event that you need to end it or on the off chance that you have an unsupported setup and can't utilize **Apache** on port **80**

To check for that:- `netstat -anp | grep ':80\s'`